# Bijective mapping from $N^+$ to the set of all rational numbers other than 0 satisfying certain condition.

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a bijective mapping $f$ from $\mathbb{N}^+$ to $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$ such that
$$|f(n)|>\frac{1}{n}$$
for all positive integer $n$?

Comment: Well, what would $f^{-1}(0)$ be? But if you want a bijection with $\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ you can almost certainly do it.

Comment: That's right, I forget this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coffemath deleted his answer rather than make a simple fix.

As noted in my comment above, you can't do it with $f(n)=0$ for some $n$, so you have to make it a bijection between $\mathbb N^+$ and $\mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}$.

Let $g:\mathbb N^+\to \mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ be any bijection.
|
Define $f$ recursively. Let $m(n)$ be the smallest positive integer such that $|g(m(n))|>\frac 1n$ and $g(m(n))\not\in\{f(1),\dots,f(n-1)\}$.

The define $f(n)=g(m(n))$.

It's fairly easy to prove that $f$ is $1-1$. Slightly harder, but not really hard, to prove that it is onto. Basically, if $r_k=\frac{p}{q}$, then $m(n)=k$ for some $n\leq k+q$.

Comment: Thomas -- I should have adjusted my now deleted answer after your comment. However your answer here is more complete than mine would have been after adjusting it. (+1)